# double click to select text from editText cause an ArithmeticException

Tags: android, android-edittext, arithmetic-expressions, appcompatactivity

in some devices when i try to select text from edittext to copy it cause an

**ArithmeticException**

im using that edittext in activity extends from **AppCompatActivity**

here is the exception

> E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback:
>   handleReceiveCallback  E/MessageQueue-JNI:
>   java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero at
>   android.widget.Editor.updateShowAsAction (Editor.java:6034)
>   android.widget.Editor$SelectionActionModeCallback.onCreateActionMode
>   (Editor.java:3208)
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView$ActionModeCallbackWrapper.onCreateActionMode
>   (PhoneWindow.java:3522)
>   android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportActionModeWrapper$CallbackWrapper.onCreateActionMode
>   (SupportActionModeWrapper.java:155)
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7$ActionModeCallbackWrapperV7.onCreateActionMode
>   (AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1644)
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.startSupportActionModeFromWindow
>   (AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:748)
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.startSupportActionMode
>   (AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:642)
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14$AppCompatWindowCallbackV14.startAsSupportActionMode
>   (AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:74)
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14$AppCompatWindowCallbackV14.onWindowStartingActionMode
>   (AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:58)
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.startActionMode
>   (PhoneWindow.java:2981)
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.startActionModeForChild
>   (PhoneWindow.java:2968) android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild
>   (ViewGroup.java:710) android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild
>   (ViewGroup.java:710) android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild
>   (ViewGroup.java:710) android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild
>   (ViewGroup.java:710) android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild
>   (ViewGroup.java:710) android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild
>   (ViewGroup.java:710) android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild
>   (ViewGroup.java:710) android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild
>   (ViewGroup.java:710) android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild
>   (ViewGroup.java:710) android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild
>   (ViewGroup.java:710) android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild
>   (ViewGroup.java:710) android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild
>   (ViewGroup.java:710) android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild
>   (ViewGroup.java:710) android.view.View.startActionMode
>   (View.java:5292) android.widget.Editor.startSelectionActionMode
>   (Editor.java:1723)
>   android.widget.Editor$SelectionModifierCursorController.onTouchEvent
>   (Editor.java:5500) android.widget.Editor.onTouchEvent
>   (Editor.java:1211) android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent
>   (TextView.java:9567) android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent
>   (View.java:8975) android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent
>   (ViewGroup.java:2709) android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent
>   (ViewGroup.java:2371)
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent
>   (ViewGroup.java:2709) android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent
>   (ViewGroup.java:2371)
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent
>   (ViewGroup.java:2709) android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent
>   (ViewGroup.java:2371)
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent
>   (ViewGroup.java:2709) android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent
>   (ViewGroup.java:2371)
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent
>   (ViewGroup.java:2709) android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent
>   (ViewGroup.java:2371) android.widget.ScrollView.dispatchTouchEvent
>   (ScrollView.java:615)
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent
>   (ViewGroup.java:2709) android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent
>   (ViewGroup.java:2371)
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent
>   (ViewGroup.java:2709) android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent
>   (ViewGroup.java:2371)
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent
>   (ViewGroup.java:2709) android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent
>   (ViewGroup.java:2371)
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent
>   (ViewGroup.java:2709) android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent
>   (ViewGroup.java:2371)
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent
>   (ViewGroup.java:2709) android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent
>   (ViewGroup.java:2371)
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent
>   (ViewGroup.java:2709) android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent
>   (ViewGroup.java:2371)
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent
>   (ViewGroup.java:2709) android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent
>   (ViewGroup.java:2371)
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent
>   (ViewGroup.java:2709) android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent
>   (ViewGroup.java:2371)
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent
>   (ViewGroup.java:2709) android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent
>   (ViewGroup.java:2371)
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent
>   (PhoneWindow.java:2568)
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent
>   (PhoneWindow.java:1776) android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent
>   (Activity.java:2866)
>   android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent
>   (WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent
>   (PhoneWindow.java:2529) android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent
>   (View.java:9180)
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent
>   (ViewRootImpl.java:4734)
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess
>   (ViewRootImpl.java:4572) android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver
>   (ViewRootImpl.java:4096)
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext
>   (ViewRootImpl.java:4149) android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward
>   (ViewRootImpl.java:4115)
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward
>   (ViewRootImpl.java:4229) android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply
>   (ViewRootImpl.java:4123)
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply
>   (ViewRootImpl.java:4286) android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver
>   (ViewRootImpl.java:4096)
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext
>   (ViewRootImpl.java:4149) android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward
>   (ViewRootImpl.java:4115) android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply
>   (ViewRootImpl.java:4123) android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver
>   (ViewRootImpl.java:4096) android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent
>   (ViewRootImpl.java:6594)
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents
>   (ViewRootImpl.java:6484) android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent
>   (ViewRootImpl.java:6455)
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent
>   (ViewRootImpl.java:6684)
>   android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent
>   (InputEventReceiver.java:185) android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce
>   (MessageQueue.java) android.os.MessageQueue.next
>   (MessageQueue.java:143) android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:130)
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5944)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
>   (ZygoteInit.java:1399)

the exception cause in this method

> android.widget.Editor.updateShowAsAction (Editor.java:6034)

here is my xml code for edittext

```
            <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/etIdNumber"
            android:hint="@string/user_profile_myInfo_add_identification_dialog_et_hint"
            android:inputType="number"
            style="@style/et_rounded_corner_white_bg"
            />
```

and here is my style

```
    <style name="et_rounded_corner_white_bg" parent="horizontal_margin">
     <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
     <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
     <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
     <item name="android:background">@drawable/editfield_bg</item>
     <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/font_very_light_gray</item>
     <item name="android:padding">@dimen/padding_5dp</item>
     <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/padding_10dp</item>
     <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>
</style>
```

Comment: post the related code

Comment: @johnrao07 no specific code i have made it only a normal edittext

Comment: on which devices it causes the problem?

Comment: @johnrao07 Samsung galaxy Note4 and Samsung Grand

Comment: And other devices it works fine? Which are those devices?

Comment: works fine on HTC m7

Comment: If you have no code to display, there isn't gona have any solution..but I don't know why I always hated samsung...!

Comment: i will update my question with my xml and style

Comment: i update the full exception may now help ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96025/discussion-between-johnrao07-and-ahmed-mousa).

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Is the problem solved? I experience the same issue. I didn't set the edittext style but it also has the "divide by zero" problem....

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs when the device is setting up copy/paste action buttons in the action bar after you double click on an EditText. It will retrieve the minWidth attribute of your actionButtonStyle. Instead of setting this to 0dp, use 1dp. Code sample:

```
<item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/myTheme.ActionButtonStyle</item>

<style name="myTheme.ActionButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbutton_bg</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/title_foreground</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingStart">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingEnd">12dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

**It will do the work!!**

```
<EditText 
 android:id="@+id/etIdNumber"
 android:hint="@string/user_profile_myInfo_add_identification_dialog_et_hint"
 android:inputType="number"
 style="@style/et_rounded_corner_white_bg"/>
```

**Remove from style this line:**

```
<item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>
```

Comment: it dose not work when i add this line the keyboard dose not open